# How to add scroll to django rendered table?

Tags: css, django, html, html-table

So here's the table. When I give `height:500px` it modifies each row's height and never the table's height and if I add `overflow-y:scroll` to `table`, `tbody` it doesn't work. The number of rows depend on how many frames exist in frame_list.
How to add scroll for this table?

```
<table id="telemetry_table1">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Frame identifier</th>
                <th>Frame Arriving Date</th>
                <th>Frame Arriving Time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

     <tbody>
        {% for frame in frame_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{frame.frame_identifier_type}}</td>
                <td>{{frame.frame_arriving_time}}</td>
                <td>{{frame.frame_arriving_date}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what is needed exactly ? can u make a fiddle of this too ?

Comment: But django is server side, how could I add that to fiddle? And yes, upvoted :P

Comment: actually i dnt know much abt django .. but what i understand is dynamically the contents are added and you want a scroll to that .. Right? correct me if i m wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, I just had to wrap the table in a div and add scroll to that. It works then.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this in your `css`

```
#telemetry_table1 {
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Fixed it, I just had to wrap the table in a div and add scroll to that. Thanks though.