# How to resize table so that hidden contents are shown on mousedrag?

Tags: jquery, html-table

When we use resize property, the table enlarges on mousedrag. However I want further rows on the table to be shown on mousedrag, with the table not changing size. 
Okay consider this
https://jsfiddle.net/o0Ldf0us/4/

**When you scroll you get the hidden contents right? I want to be able to view them not by scroll, but by mousedrag on that little resize option.**

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<table id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading1</th>
        <th>Heading2</th>
        <th>Heading3</th>
        <th>Heading4</th>
        <th>Heading5</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Data1.1</td>
        <td>Data2.1</td>
        <td>Data3.1</td>
        <td>Data4.1</td>
        <td>Data5.1</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Data1.2</td>
        <td>Data2.2</td>
        <td>Data3.2</td>
        <td>Data4.2</td>
        <td>Data5.2</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Data1.3</td>
        <td>Data2.3</td>
        <td>Data3.3</td>
        <td>Data4.3</td>
        <td>Data5.3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**CSS:**

```
#example, th, td{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
div{
height:100px;
width:200px;  
overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: please be specific and also provide things you have done

Comment: Done. When you scroll you get the hidden contents right? I want to be able to view them not by scroll, but by mousedrag on that little resize option.

Comment: I have put answer .. have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to div css

```
resize: both;
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/o0Ldf0us/5/)**

Comment: That was simple. Thanks

Comment: Could you have a look at this too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023959/how-to-add-scroll-to-django-rendered-table